# Add parameter UIbutton to NotificationCenter observer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsnotificationcenter

I have a Notification observer which triggers a function that takes a parameter of type `UIButton`.

I have been constantly trying to make the notifications work, but for some reason I am getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Following is my code :

```
func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, willDisplay button: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
        let highlightedImage = UIImage(named: items[atIndex])
        button.setImage(highlightedImage, for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        switch atIndex {
        case 0:
            button.tag = 0
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(button, selector: #selector(handleEmotion), name: Notification.Name("sendnotif"), object: nil)
        case 1:
            print("Do something else")
        default:
            break
        }

    }

@objc func handleEmotion(_ note: Notification, sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            sender.layer.borderColor = blueColor.cgColor
            sender.layer.borderWidth = 2
        }
    }
```

My concern is how exactly should I make this bit of code work for the `case 0` and subsequently for all the cases and how should I effectively pass my button to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using Notification is necessary. One way to it, without changing much of your code is to addGestureRecognizer to the buttons and pre-setting the buttons' tag with their respective index when you create them.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.tag = index
button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleEmotion(_:))))

func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, willDisplay button: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
    let highlightedImage = UIImage(named: items[atIndex])
    button.setImage(highlightedImage, for: .normal)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}

@objc func handleEmotion(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.view?.tag == 0 {
        sender.layer.borderColor = blueColor.cgColor
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 2
    }
}
```

And about the notification, in that case, NotificationCenter.addObserver shouldn't be put there. It should be called only once, so maybe put it in viewDidLoad(). Then in the circleMenu func, what should be done when the button is tapped is to post the notification and not add observer.

Comment: Well thats exactly the reason I didn't added observer as self. Instead I put the button to be clicked. But I chose notifications since I have to trigger `handleEmotion` with an occurrence of an event. Also, I dont want to tap the button. I just want the layout changed.

Comment: I see. In that case, how about instead of calling NotificationCenter, you can just call handleEmotion function: button.tag = 0. handleEmotion(button). Then, for the handleEmotion func, just make it a normal function: func handleEmotion(sender: UIButton)

Comment: Alright, So if you see my code in the question, I have multiple cases in the Delegate method. Each case should be triggered when an even occurs. So calling the function is really not an option here :|

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(button, selector: #selector(handleEmotion), name: Notification.Name("sendnotif"), object: nil)
```

With the above line, you are adding button as target and hence it expects handleEmotion to be defined in the implementation of UIButton. And hence you are getting the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

If you have access to the button, when posting the notification, what you can do is. Add the observer at a viewWillAppear

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleEmotion), name: Notification.Name("sendnotif"), object: nil)
```

And then modify the code as

```
@objc func handleEmotion(note: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = note.userInfo {
        if let button = userInfo["button"] {
         if button.view?.tag == 0 {
            button.layer.borderColor = blueColor.cgColor
            button.layer.borderWidth = 2
         }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use below while posting the notification

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("sendnotif"), object: self, userInfo: ["button":button])
```

Comment: Theres an issue with your post notification. The button will be an unresolved identifier.

Comment: yeah I just wrote given an understanding that you have access to button you want to change when posting then notification which you can pass in the post notification